# python return function

Tags: python, return

I have a program to generate a list of 10 random numbers between 1-5, then counts how many times each number appears, and then creates a new list with the duplicates removed.  I keep getting that certain global names are not defined.  I seem to be confused about the return function.  I need it in this format though, so I can't just put print statements at the end of each function.  Any help?

```
def main():
    """print output of program"""
    firstList= []
    randomTen(firstList)
    countInts(firstList)
    removeDuplicates(firstList)
    print(firstList)
    print('The number of times one appears is', ones)
    print('The number of times two appears is', twos)
    print('The number of times three appears is', threes)
    print('The number of times four appears is', fours)
    print('The number of times five appears is', fives)
    print(secondList)


def randomTen(firstList):
    """return list of ten integers"""
    for num in range(1,11):
        x= int(random.randint(1,5))
        firstList.append(x)
    return firstList


def countInts(firstList):
    """count the number of times each integer appears in the list"""
    ones= firstList.count(1)
    twos= firstList.count(2)
    threes= firstList.count(3)
    fours= firstList.count(4)
    fives= firstList.count(5)
    return ones, twos, threes, fours, fives

def removeDuplicates(firstList):
    """return list of random integers with the duplicates removed"""
    secondList=set(firstList)
    return secondList
```

Comment: post the traceback and error message you're getting.

Comment: well it says ones, but I imagine if it means ones, twos, threes, fours, fives, and secondList but is stoping at ones

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#39>", line 1, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/tinydancer9454/Documents/randomInts.py", line 26, in main
    print('The number of times one appears is', ones)
NameError: global name 'ones' is not defined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you're ignoring the return values of your functions. For example,

```
countInts(firstList)
```

should read

```
ones, twos, threes, fours, fives = countInts(firstList)
```

Without this, `ones` *et al* do not exist in `main()`.

The same goes for the other functions (except `randomTen()` which, in addition to returning `firstList`, also modifies it in place).

Answer (score 1):

[NPE's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15343913/1322401) is exactly correct that you need to assign the return values of your functions to local variables.

That said, here is a little more pythonic way of accomplishing the same task.

```
from collections import Counter
from random import randint

nums = [randint(1, 5) for _ in range(10)]
counts = Counter(nums)
uniq_nums = set(nums) # or list(counts.keys())
```

To display the values do

```
print nums
for word, num in (('one', 1), ('two', 2), ('three', 3), ('four', 4), ('five', 5)):
    print 'The number of times %s appears is %s' % (word, counts[num])
print uniq_nums
```

Which prints:

```
[4, 5, 1, 4, 1, 2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
The number of times one appears is 3
The number of times two appears is 3
The number of times three appears is 1
The number of times four appears is 2
The number of times five appears is 1
set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```